# consequences of not calling Thread.Join()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, operating-system

If I spin up a new thread in C#, can I just fire and forget without worrying about the thread being joined?

```
void DoSomething()
{
  var worker = new Worker();
  var start = new ThreadStart(worker.DoStuff);
  var thread = new Thread(start);
  thread.Start();

  // do something else...
  // who knows how long it'll take...

  // exit without calling thread.Join()

}
```

Are there consequences to writing this code?

Comment: This isn't specific to C#, this applies to other languages as well.  It's more specific to OSes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is safe insofar as the thread will continue until completion by itself, you do not need to have a reference to the `Thread` object to keep it alive, nor will the behavior of the thread change in any way.

The only thing you give up is the ability to later on join on the thread, or check its status, but it is *absolutely safe to fire and forget threads*.

However, if you fire and forget a thread set as a background thread, that thread might not run to completion if the program exits before the thread completes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can absolutely *fire and forget* a thread without ever calling `Join`. There won't be any *bad* consequences. If it is a background thread and the process terminates before the thread has finished executing it will bring it down anyway.

Answer (score 4):

It depends.

A [background thread](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4272/net-threading-part-ii/6/) will accept death and not keep the process alive. Not joining means ... well, possible early death. This is slightly different than a foreground thread in terms of "fire and forget" semantics.

Happy coding.

Comment: A thread created and started using my method above would be considered a "background thread", correct? Thus, there is a potential consequence to not joining (that being if the original/foreground thread exits or terminates).

Comment: @kindohm `new Thread(...)` creates a foreground thread by default -- so it is "safe" from being auto-reaped (but perhaps too safe and might prevent normal termination). Use `IsBackground` to inspect/change. (This can be done after the thread is running.)

Comment: This doesn't answer his question.